# El servicio de búsqueda de SharePoint Server 2019 no me recupera unas propiedades rastreadas de tipo metadatos

Tags: sharepoint

Tengo un problema en el servicoi de búsqueda de SharePoint. En mi máquina de desarrollo puedo recuperar sin problemas unas propiedades rastreadas de tipo metadatos administrados. Tengo varias reglas de rastreo para incluir o excluir contenido.

Mi problema viene cuando intento hacer lo mismo en el entorno de preproducción, el cúal tiene un certificado ssl (lo pongo como info porque no sé si es algo a tener en cuenta)

Estas son las reglas que tengo en PRE:
[image: PreProduction rules]

La configuración de cada regla (son iguales todos) es la siguiente:
[image: Configuración de la regla]

¿Alguien podría decirme cuál puede ser el problema? Tengo activa la característica de "filtrado y navegación por metadatos" en cada spweb de la colección de sitios.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes de realizar un rasteo hay que comprobar que al menos un documento o ítem tiene valores en la columna de metadatos administrados.
Yo tuve un problema con el archivo hosts y no estaba viendo correctamente el entorno, por eso no funcionaba.